# Sitecore Installation SQL Issue

Tags: sql, permissions, sitecore, sitecore-instance-manager

I'm trying to install sitecore using the Sitecore Instance Manager and on the step where I need to choose network service folder I'm getting this [error](http://gyazo.com/c09bb57aae33c61868e653ae438a3c81).

I've provided full access permissions to this folder to everyone but it wasn't help.

Do anybody have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Can you summarize the error your getting the question text?  This will make it easier for someone to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known issue. Here is [link](https://bitbucket.org/alienlab/sitecore-instance-manager/wiki/KnownIssue-SqlServerDefaultAccount) to workaround.

You should change account that run SQL server instance and grant that account full rights to folder where you will install your instances.